# Binding datagrid to viewmodel

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

What am I doing wrong in the mvvm pattern below wrt data-binding?

What I see is a `DataGrid` showing an extra column and an extra row (both empty), why is that?

And: how must I proceed to get my view to select the first item by default?

view-model:

```
public class Instance { public string Name { get; set; } }

public class BaseData
{
    public ObservableCollection<Instance> Instances { get { return instances; } }
    public BaseData()
        {
            var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(fetch);
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(fetched);
        }
    void fetch(){...}
    void fetched(..){... // raise event 'Fetched' to the view }
}
```

view (xaml):

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dgInstances" ItemsSource="{Binding Instances}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instance" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

view (code-behind):

```
BaseData BaseData;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += delegate
    {
        BaseData = new BaseData();
        BaseData.Fetched += basedata_fetched;
    };
}

void basedata_fetched(...)
{
    DataContext = BaseData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) CanUserAddRows="False" will removed the extra row .

2)  Width="*" on the column  will stretch to the grid's width and hide what looks like another column.

```
   <DataGrid  CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dgInstances" ItemsSource="{Binding Instances}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instance" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Correct. How strange is such a design.

Comment: :) , yes they expect you to configure what isn't

Answer (score 1):

To select the first item in the DataGrid your definition of your datagrid should be

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dgInstances" ItemsSource="{Binding Instances}" SelectedIndex="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to turn off AutoGenerateColumns on your DataGrid and declare your own columns to display whatever you want.

As to selecting your items, you can bind the DataGrid's SelectedItem to a ViewModel property.
Then you can set SelectedItem to your first Instance.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Instances}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInstance, Mode=TwoWay}">
               <DataGrid.Columns>
                   ...
               </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I already used AutoGenerateColumns="False" it has no effect on the extra column, that perhaps is not a columns but kind of "remaining space".

Comment: SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInstance}" is probably correct, it doesn't work the first time, therefore I need SelectedIndex="0"

Comment: By default columns will only take the space they need, if the grid is wider than what the columns need, you'll end up with some extra space.
Set one of your columns to Width="*", it should take up the remaining space. For the SelectedInstance not working, you'll have to make sure an OnPropertyChanged is raised, so the view gets notified when the property is changed.